# How to fix: ReferenceError: validateEmail is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make Register using EJS. Therefore, I'm checking

1. If all input fields have values or not
2. Is Email valid or not
3. Password Length has to be < 6 characters
4. Is Email already register or not
   And give them a message if they do not comply with the above conditions. To Check all these conditions I have the following code inside the userCtrl.js file
   userCtrl.js

```js
const Users = require("../models/userModel");

const userCtrl = {
  //! Register User
  register: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { name, email, password } = req.body;
      // Check If All fields are filled with values or not
      if (!name || !email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ masg: "Please fill allfields." });
      }
      // Check If email is valid
      if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ masg: "Please enter valid email." });
      }
      //Check password length
      if (password.length < 6) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ masg: "Password must be atleast 6 characters long." });
      }
      const user = await Users.findOne({ email });
      // Check If email is already registered
      if (await Users.findOne({ email })) {
        return res.status(400).json({ masg: "User already exists." });
      }
      res.json({ msg: "User Registered Successfully!" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  },
};

//! Exporting User Controller
module.exports = userCtrl;
```

Here is user Module for refrance.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your name"],
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your email"],
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your password"],
    trim: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0, // 0 for user, 1 for admin
  },
  avator: {
    type: String,
    default:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/manix/image/upload/v1639722719/avator/istockphoto-1214428300-170667a_c4fsdt.jpg",
  },
});
//! Exporting User Modules
module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
```

But when I try to register users using Postman then I got this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zWU7.png)

**Please Help me to fix this issue.**

Comment: You have not added the function definition for the validateEmail, due to which it is undefined in the call stack, and you are getting that error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/10281244 you can refer this function to validate your email.

Comment: You can also use this repo to do this in an easier and cleaner way: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably happening here

```
if (!validateEmail(email))
```

Where is your `validateEmail()` function located?